# daily 15 minutes downtime for half a year on GAE-python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Happens every midnight PST.

Makes even the built-in 404 responses take **minutes** to complete (with DeadlineError, of course).
I reported it back in March, others must have done before.

Is there something to avoid in the code to somehow alleviate this?

Using python2.5 on M/S datastore.

Comment: Aren't you over some quota?

Comment: Nope, all goes back to normal right after these 15 minutes. It happens 1 hour into the quota day.

Answer (score 1):

As per here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/usingmasterslave

The master/slave datastore is deprecated; you should probably try to migrate to the high replication datastore. The HRD is much less susceptible to abnormal latency events in the backend, as it distributes requests to multiple datacenters.

You can migrate by following these directions:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration

*(Full disclosure: I work for Google as an SRE. While I do not work directly on AppEngine, I maintain services that run on the same backend technologies as AppEngine.)*

Comment: The problem is at the frontend. Would happily migrate to HRD (and will, when the time permits), but this downtime affects it too: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8901